# i am getting "OperationalError at /admin/login/" no such table: auth_user"post docker container deployment

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

--entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#APP_PORT=${PORT:-8000}
cd /app/
/opt/venv/bin/python manage.py migrate --noinput
/opt/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm django_k8s.wsgi:application --bind "0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: Have you run migrations in the production environment?  Do you have any relevant code that you can include in the question; is this a programming question, or more of a deployment issue?

Comment: Yes i did migrations.